# リポジトリのローカル化

Tags: centos, yum

CentOSを使っています。
リポジトリが消されても大丈夫なようにローカルに配置しようと思っています。

途中省略しますが

```
reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=epel-multimedia --download_path=/repo/epel-multimedia
```

で/repo/配下にepel-multimediaで公開されているrpmを置きました。

```
mkdir /repo/Packages
mv /repo/epel-multimedia/*.rpm /repo/epel-multimedia/Packages/.
createrepo /repo/epel-multimedia
```

でリポジトリの作成を行っています。

一方、/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-multimedia.repoを

```
[epel-multimedia]
name=negativo17 - Multimedia
baseurl=baseurl=file:///repo/epel-multimedia
enabled=0
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgkey=https://negativo17.org/repos/RPM-GPG-KEY-slaanesh
gpgcheck=1
enabled_metadata=1
metadata_expire=6h
type=rpm-md
repo_gpgcheck=0
```

にして、

```
# yum --enablerepo=epel-multimedia install libva
```

を実行したところ、

```
Repository 'epel-multimedia': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = 'baseurl=file:///repo/epel-multimedia'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
```

ローカルに置いたはずのリポジトリが見つからないとエラーが出ます。
こちら解決方法をご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純な記述ミスが原因かと。

```ini
baseurl=baseurl=file:///repo/epel-multimedia
```

ではなく、正しくは

```ini
baseurl=file:///repo/epel-multimedia
```